# React native system trace custom events

Tags: react-native, android-studio, profiling, trace

I am using Android studio system trace to profile the performance of my application,
however the data I see in the system trace is very general, there are bottlenecks on `draw`, or `prepare_to_draw`.
Is there any way in React Native to add custom traces, so I can better see in the profiling which part is actually taking longer?

Comment: Checkout Flipper. It is a platform for debugging iOS, Android and React Native apps. Visualize, inspect, and control your apps from a simple desktop interface. I use it for my react native applications, it shows system trace, logs, network calls, CPU utilization, etc.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, flipper crashes every time I start profiling after 5 seconds.  I didn't dig deep to figure out why exactly. My react native debugger also stopped working. basically when I click on the start button on profiling there, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I can still use both of them for other purposes, just not for profiling.